# What is the essential semantic difference between "sein" and "werden" for passive voice?

Tags: grammar, passive

I know that in German the passive voice is formed with both *sein* and *werden*:

*Das Haus wird gebaut*

or

*Das Haus ist gebaut*

Are these two forms of the passive voice interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix this, I guess this is a "false friend" for native English speakers. The passive of "I build the house/Ich baue das Haus" is "The house **is** built (by me)/Das Haus **wird** (von mir) gebaut" and not "Das Haus **ist** gebaut". The latter would rather mean "The house has been built" or to exaggerate that the "ist" is for describung a state "The house **is** something that has the property of having come to existence by a process of building". Or you can view "Das Haus ist gebaut" as meaning the same as "Das Haus ist bezugsfertig/The house **is** ready to move in"

Comment: Are the following examples correct and demonstrate well the idea? --

1) _Das fleisch ist gebraten._

"The meat is fried". I.e. not raw. Here we describe a quality of the subject. _Gebraten_ acts as an adjective.

--

2) _Das fleisch wird gebraten._

The meat is being fried. I.e. it is in the process of being fried. Here we describe an action that affects the subject. _Gebraten_ acts as a participle.

Answer (score 4):

These are semantically completely different expressions: `gefragt sein` is a fixed expression, a trope, if you will, which means `to be in demand`

On the other hand `gefragt werden` is directly derived from `fragen - ask` and means `being asked`

Comment: This is not what I've asked. Replace the verb, and the question remains: there are two types of the passive voice in German, one of which is formed with _sein_, while the other is formed with _werden_. But I don't know when to use them correctly, although, technically, I know both their grammatical structures (as shown in the body of my question).

Comment: You asked if the two forms are interchangeable and I answered "no". Here the difference between "Vorgangspassiv (process) - ich werde gefragt" and "Zustandspassiv (state)- ich bin gefragt" is at hand.

Comment: OK. So what is the difference between Vorgangspassiv and Zustandspassiv? How can I use them correctly without using one in lieu of the other? Can you please tell me that?

Comment: When the passive is built with present perfect participle an "werden" it is used to describe a process, something with beginning, end and a limited time frame. When built with present perfect participle and "sein" (or "bin" in this case) it describes a result or a state. Here it is the state of being always asked, so to speak, and thus being in demand. This is where the fixed expression "gefragt sein" derives its meaning from. Did this clarify a bit?

Comment: @indoxica: Wenn Deine Frage unklar ist, dann solltest Du sie verbessern, nicht andere auffordern es für Dich zu tun.