# Werden vs Sind in statement

Tags: grammar, passive, past-participle

What is the difference in phrasing this statement, are both grammatically correct?

> Tabak und Alkohol **werden** unter der Hand importiert.
>
> Tabak und Alkohol **sind** unter der Hand importiert.

Comment: “Vorgangspassiv” vs. “Zustandspassiv”. Also consider _sind … importiert **worden**_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the essential semantic difference between "sein" and "werden" for passive voice?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/what-is-the-essential-semantic-difference-between-sein-and-werden-for-passiv) Also related: [The three(?) German passive past tenses](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20164/the-three-german-passive-past-tenses/20168)

Answer (score 2):

The first means approximately "Tobacco and alcohol are being imported clandestinely." It might be used in the report of a government agency about the state of smuggling in their domain of authority. (Think "We have a smuggling problem!")

The second means approximately "Tobacco and alcohol are clandestine imports." It might be said by someone trying to convince you to go to a really rad party he's throwing. (Think "This shit is the good stuff, man! It's only legal in Tennessee!")

Answer (score 1):

„Werden“ is used to describe an event, „sein“ is used to describe the result. The second sentence is wrong, however, or at least awkward. I think it would sound wrong if translated to English as well. Take another one:

> Das Haus wird abgerissen. (The house is being demolished)
>   Das Haus ist abgerissen. (The house is demolished)

However, take note that in German, Passive Voice with „werden“ and „sein“ do not necessarily form a pair:

> Das Passiv wird im Deutschunterricht früh gelehrt.
>   *Das Passiv ist im Deutschunterricht früh gelehrt.

Passive Voice with „werden“ originally meant that something becomes something else, but today, it often means that something happens all the time.

Comment: The second example is not *wrong* - I do however agree it sounds clumsy. In a real conversation you would probably go with a participle like *Die hatten auf ihrer Party geschmuggelten Tabak und Alkohol*