# Die Lampe ist repariert vs Die Lampe wurde repariert

Tags: passive

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diese zwei Sätze? Ihr könnt extra Beispiele bilden.

Comment: Or this: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/what-is-the-essential-semantic-difference-between-sein-and-werden-for-passiv

Comment: I don't know what the best duplicate is, but check https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Zustandspassiv.

Answer (score 1):

Beispiel:Die Lampe wurde repariert, funktioniert aber jetzt schon wieder nicht.

Beispiel: Die Lampe ist repariert. Deshalb funktioniert sie.

"Die Lampe wurde repariert." Das ist eine Beschreibung des Zustandes der Lampe in der Vergangenheit. Der Zustand mag sich mittlerweile geändert haben.

"Die Lampe ist repariert" : Das ist eine Beschreibung des Zustandes der Lampe im Präsens. Die Aussage gilt jetzt.

Comment: Warum benutzen wir '' AOK wurde 1884 gegründet.'' nicht ''AOK ist1884 gegründet''